# Can't pick image from gallery

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I am coding an application for recognizing plant species. I want to pick an image and show that on screen but i can't. Image returns null. Although i choose photo from gallery, it still says "no image selected".

I also added read_external_storage permission to android manifests.

[image: as you can see.]

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:tflite/tflite.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class PlantSpeciesRecognition extends StatefulWidget {
  var model;

  PlantSpeciesRecognition(this.model);

  @override
  _PlantSpeciesRecognitionState createState() =>
      _PlantSpeciesRecognitionState();
}

class _PlantSpeciesRecognitionState extends State<PlantSpeciesRecognition> {
  File _image;
  bool _busy = false;
  List _recognitions;


  Future chooseImageGallery() async {
    debugPrint("choose image function");
    var image = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    //var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (image == null) {
      debugPrint("choose image if");
      return;
    }
    //await analyzeTFLite();

    setState(() {
      debugPrint("choose image set state");
      _busy = true;
      _image = image as File;
    });
  }
   
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> stackChildren = [];
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    //stackChildren.clear();

    stackChildren.add(Positioned(
      top: 0.0,
      left: 0.0,
      width: size.width,
      child: _image == null ? Text("No Image Selected") : Image.file(_image),
    ));

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Plant Species Recognition'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: chooseImageGallery,
        tooltip: 'Pick Image',
        child: Icon(Icons.image),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: stackChildren,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `if (image == null) ` If image not is null then what was its value?

Comment: And why would `_image` then be null?

Comment: that's what i asked.

Comment: What was the value of `image` you forgot to tell.

Comment: `_image = image as File;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is normal because it is not the file that is returned. Correct the following line:

```
setState(() {
      debugPrint("choose image set state");
      _busy = true;
      _image = File(image.path); //change this line.
    });
```